# httr POST with keywordtool.io

Tags: r, post, httr

I'm struggling to get httr to work with an API that my company is currently using and for the life of me I can't work out why.

```
x <- c("Electronic cigarette",                                       
"Cloud-chasing electronic cigarette",                       
"Safety of electronic cigarettes",                            
"Electronic cigarette aerosol and liquid",                    
"Openvape",                                                   
"Blu eCigs",                                                  
"Regulation of electronic cigarettes",                        
"PAX Labs",                                                   
"Construction of electronic cigarettes",                      
"Vape shop",                                                  
"Hon Lik",                                                    
"Dragonite International Limited",                            
"Positions of medical organizations on electronic cigarettes",
"Evolv",                                                      
"List of vaping bans in the United States",                   
"VMR Products",                                               
"List of electronic cigarette brands",                        
"Electronic cigarettes in Australia",                         
"LOGIC electronic cigarette",                               
"VUSE electronic cigarette",                                
"NJOY",                                                       
"R. J. Reynolds Vapor Company",                               
"MarkTen",                                                    
"Vista Vapors",                                               
"Riccardo Polosa",                                            
"Ten Motives",
)

vars <- list(
keyword = as.character(x),
apikey = "apikeyhere",
metrics_location = "2826",
metrics_language = "en",
metrics_network = "googlesearchnetwork", 
metrics_currency = "USD",
output = "json"
)


res <- POST("https://api.keywordtool.io/v2/search/volume/google"
        , body = vars
        , encode = "json", verbose())
```

when I do this for different metrics locations (e.g., 2826 is the UK), it just returns the data for the US which is the default. Is seems to be reading the data in the keyword portion of the list, but then ignoring the rest. The documentation for the API can be found here (unfortunatley the API is paid): https://keywordtool.io/api/documentation#examples

I'm able to get different results for the US and the UK when I format as a php script and run via the terminal, I just don't seem to be able to get it to work with httr. Ideas would be welcome.

edit:

two of the parameters needed to have their values in a list, even if for just one item. poor comprehension on my part.

Comment: If you can get it to work with php, try posting to a site like https://requestb.in/ where you can see what's actually being sent to the server. Then compare that to what you get when you use `httr` to do the same. There is likely some difference in the requests you are sending.

Comment: thanks @MrFlick, good suggestion. I've uploaded the output to imgur: https://imgur.com/a/T6rkc 
the output nearest the top is a php script, the lower is httr. The headers are different, but not in a way that seems relevant to the differing output, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a problem with the params , the metrics_location seems to be overwritten by the default GLOBAL/ENGLISH or its not loaded .
First check https://keywordtool.io/api .
Then simply add: "https://api.keywordtool.io/v2/search/volume/google**?metrics_location=[NUMBERS]** to the url . It worked for me .